# Append UI Images from array to slideshow swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiimage

I'm trying to make a slideshow with this library

https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

So i'm making a query, i bring some images and i append them here

```
var sliderArray = [UIImage]()
var testimg:UIImage!

let idaki = recipeObj.objectId
let pointer2 = PFObject(outDataWithClassName:"Recipes", objectId: idaki!)
let galquery = PFQuery(className:"sliderRecipes")
galquery.whereKey("recipe", equalTo: pointer2)
galquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                count += 1

                let glrimg = object["sliderImage"] as! PFFile
                glrimg.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData3: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData2 = imageData3 {
                            self.testimg = UIImage(data:imageData2)
                            print(self.testimg)
                            print(self.sliderArray)
                            self.sliderArray.append(UIImage(data:imageData2)!)




                        }
                        if count == objects.count { print(self.sliderArray) }
                    }
                }



                // print("test")
                // print(self.sliderPinakas)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
}
```

And after all this i DONT have an array with images. In the print above it first shows the `empty` array and after that it shows the prints of UI Images that i want to show them like this to a slider

```
slideshow.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))!, ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage2"))!])
```

but instead of having to do it with the name, `UIImage(named: "myImage"))!` i would like to do it this way

```
self.slider.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: self.testimg)])
```

for all the images of the array, cause the above line shows only one.
Is there anyone that could help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pass to `self.slider.setImageInputs` array of all objects ImageSource `[ImageSource(image: self.testimg1), ImageSource(image: self.testimg2), ...]` etc., not only one object [ImageSource(image: self.testimg)].

If you add images like:
`self.slider.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: self.testimg)])`
`self.slider.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: self.testimg2)])`
you'll simply replace first image with second.

Create new array, enumerate all images from `sliderArray`, and append they to array ImageSource(image: self.testimg1) objects.

Also remember, you have to call this from block `glrimg.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`!

add before `for`

```
var count = 0
```

and add inside block

```
count +=1
if count == objects.count {
    print(self.sliderArray)
}.
```

That will print array when all objects finished loads (they can loads in chaotic order).

Comment: could you see any issue of the first `sliderArray` ? Because i append images but it shows me an emty array after all

Comment: and where you declare self.testimg?

Comment: What do you get from `print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")`?

Comment: from `print(self.testimg)`?

Comment: i get the UIImage that is being downloaded from parse. Although it prints first the array and then the images... that means that it didnt have the time to append them !

Comment: It append, but you print before this. You retrive images in block, but print array out of block. Block yet not performed, when you print an array. Move `print(self.sliderArray)` in block. See at updated answer (last line).

Comment: But i want the final array outside the for loop and the get data in background

Comment: add `var count = 1` before `for` and add inside block `count +=1` and `if count == objects.count { print(self.sliderArray) }`. That will print array when all objects finished loads (they can loads in chaotic order).

Comment: I think i'm dealing with asynchronous downloading images that dont have the time to be downloaded and appended to the UI Image array. So i guess it has to do something with the completion

Comment: No, I sure, they appended to array, Try, like I wrote in previous comment.

Comment: its still empty :/

Comment: Try replace `print(self.testimg)` with `print(self.sliderArray)`. What does it print?

Comment: it prints only the last image of the results !

Comment: Try replace `self.sliderArray.append(self.testimg)` with `self.sliderArray.append(UIImage(data:imageData2))`

Comment: share content of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117143/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-igor).

Comment: save my day Thanks